# IBOutlet is not connecting in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoapods, iboutlet

I cannot get my IBOutlet to connect from my view to my storyboard. I have a couple of cocoa pods installed and have no idea what could be causing the issue.

I am really new to developing.

My explain image below

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you provide screenshots or something? It is really hard to follow where the mistake could be

Comment: Thanks for responding quickly, I added a screenshot in the original post.

Comment: Why cant you connect? What happens when you try?

Comment: Nothing happens, for the IBAction on the bottom I did the usual control and drag into the vc but after I filled out the data and clicked connect nothing happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My hypothesis is that your "Points Redemption" VC is not linked with your custom class, "APEnt_Go".

Try selecting the view controller from storyboard, open Identity Inspector in Utilities and select your custom class.

Answer (score 0):

I think your class is not linked with your view Controller.

Go to Main.storyboard -> select view controller -> go to identity inspector -> give class name ("APEnt_Go")into class text area -> then Enter